# Order by random and LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I want to get random row from database, but limit it using some content.

For example, table's definition:

`id | content | tags`

The query is: `SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`.

Tags part looks like: `tag1, tag2, tag42`. So, for example, I want one random row from ones which have `tag42` or `tag2` inside `tags`.

Some pseudocode:

`SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY RAND() WHERE tags LIKE '%tag42%' OR '%tags2%' LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Your ORDER BY and WHERE are the wrong way round?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pseudocode is almost correct, except you have order of clauses wrong: `WHERE` comes before `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE tags LIKE '%tag42%' OR '%tags2%' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

See the [documentation for `SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html), to never get wrong again

Comment: It would take much time on a big table.

Comment: Yes it would. But hey, he's keeping tags as a comma delimited string!

Comment: Yeah, the result isn't so big and there are less than 200 rows in db. That's why the tags are stored as a string, etc.